# Problem migrating w/ sqlite3, receive error message-> undefined method `prerequisites' for nil:NilClass

Tags: sqlite, rake

I'm working on the RoR3 Tutorial and i'm  on chapter 6 when I tried the **rakedb:migrate** command.  I received the message:

rake aborted!
undefined method `prerequisites' for nil:NilClass

I ignored the changes to the Gemfile because it already was installing sqlite3.  When I changed it to **'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5' :required => 'sqlite3'**, i got an ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished message when trying to view the page locally.  So, I just decided to not make that change.

I am using lion os, ruby 1.9.2p290, rails 3.1.0.rc8.  Thx!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm working on the same tutorial at the moment, and ran into the same issue. After some digging, it turns out this is a bug with rspec-rails. If you look at rpsec-rails' change log for 2.6.1

> guard against calling prerequisites on nil default rake task (Jack
>   Dempsey)

the book also doesn't get a chance to go into detail on what's going on when you run "bundle install", turns out bundler is meant to solve application dependencies: http://gembundler.com/rationale.html

Anyway, this was the solution: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1723

Change 'rspec-rails' under :development in your gemfile to:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1.beta1'
```

and 'rspec' under :test to

```
gem 'rspec', '2.6'
```

worked for me. Let me know if you want to work through the book together!